# Have scrollable div fill up the above of BottomNavigation bar?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a bottom navigation bar with fixed positioning and above it a scrollable div displaying some cardlists.

I took reference from the Material-UI doc [here](https://material-ui.com/components/bottom-navigation/) and [here](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation/#) but I could not figure out how to set the div above the bottom navigation bar so that it fills up all the remaining space.

If I simply fix the nav bar to the bottom with z-index set to a high value, the bottom of the above div will be covered. And I also tried using flex box, but that didn't seem to work with a fixed nav bar at the bottom.

I want to avoid setting percentage height on the nav bar and the div above because I think that would not scale well on difference screen sizes. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set it up so it doesn't use position absolute/fixed, since you can't use a defined height. What you can do however is have a `flex container` component that will automatically fill the `body` with a `height: 100vh;`. Inside you will put your `content-holder` component and it will have the styles `flex:1;` so it will always expand to the max, and `overflow-y: auto;` so it will display a scrollbar in case the content overflows. Inside `content-holder` you will have all the content you need.

`BottomNavigation` will be a sibling of `content-holder` and will always stay at the bottom.

You can check the following [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflowmaterial-ui-bottom-navigation-bar-vp7oj) and I've pasted the code below.

```js
import React from "react";
import BottomNavigation from "@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation";
import BottomNavigationAction from "@material-ui/core/BottomNavigationAction";
import RestoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Restore";
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Favorite";
import LocationOnIcon from "@material-ui/icons/LocationOn";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="content-holder">
        <div className="content">
          <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
          <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <BottomNavigation>
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Recents" icon={<RestoreIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Favorites" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />
        <BottomNavigationAction label="Nearby" icon={<LocationOnIcon />} />
      </BottomNavigation>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content-holder {
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
  /* you dont need this, it will grow based on the content */
  min-height: 200vh;
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid hardcoding the height for the bottom bar and the div so that the page can fit different screen sizes.

Comment: Then make the `bottom navigation bar` relative and not fixed.

Comment: but I need the bottomnavigation stick to the bottom and the above div scrollable in the remaining space, having bottomnavigation relative would defeat both?

Comment: Check the edit I made to the answer. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it was too late but you can use padding bottom for the container of your content.

```
padding-bottom:60px;
```

that's work for me with bottom navigator material-ui!